# Are 3D graphics always better than 2D?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

In preparation for making my Leviathan game engine, i realized I have only researched 2D graphics up to level 3. Are 2D graphics ever better than 3D graphics of the same level, for particular genres perhaps, or is it strictly a cost thing?

Comment: Game Dev Tycoon question titles alway make my vote-to-close trigger finger itch until I see the tag. ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes they are](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Raw_Data_for_Review_Algorithm#Tech_Level) equal at some levels.

Graphics are calculated as tech level during the [review phase](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Review_Algorithm). 3D graphics only overtake 2D graphics at V4, and every version after that. 3D V2 and 2D V2/3 are all equal, as well as 3D V3 and 2D V4/5.

Comment: Is there no relationship between topic/genre and graphics type then?

Comment: @kotekzot there are [platform/genre](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Raw_Data_for_Review_Algorithm#Platform_Genre_Combinations) relationships, but not between topic/genre/graphics as far as I am aware.